# How to do Sorting in CActiveDataProvider in YII?

Tags: sorting, yii, cactivedataprovider

I write this but it doesn't do any effect in views.

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Example', array(
  'sort'=>array(
    'defaultOrder'=>'title ASC',
  )
));
```

Is any changes in view needed ?

Comment: Nope, no change to the view is necessary. Did you try switching it up, maybe it was already sorted like that- try putting title DESC.

Comment: maybe you have order on your model criteria.

Answer (score 1):

**Example Code:**

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('display_order',$this->display_order);
$sort = new CSort();
$sort->defaultOrder=array('display_order' => CSort::SORT_DESC);
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
     ),
    'sort'=>$sort,
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
'defaultOrder'=>array('title'=>CSort::SORT_ASC)
```